# Can I use Google Visualization API in Java Swing Application?

Tags: java, swing, google-visualization

I want to use google visualization API to draw some charts in a Java Swing Application.

I have tried with JEditorPane which can load a HTML page in the swing application, but it doesn't support Javascript.

And I have tried another open source java browser LOBO, but I failed again as it is not strong enough to render google visualization api.

I have also read something with GWT, but it will generates Javascript and I still don't know how to use it in Swing. So it is not what I want.

Is it possible to use google visualization API in Java swing application?

Comment: The Google Visualization API requires Javascript. Google has a Chart API that returns an image http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/ instead. The Visualization API relies on JS hacks in order to function properly in older browsers.

Comment: Ever had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

I was using [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) to draw charts in my swing application. It's pretty simply in use.

Comment: but jfreechart produces static chart images not interactive ones

Answer (score 0):

[charts4j](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) will be a proper solution. Example code for displaying a chart via Swing can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/SwingExample.java#46)